# Is a question involving TinkerCAD (real-time Arduino circuit simulator) off-topic?

Tags: discussion

TinkerCAD's forum is very limited on how to ask questions (with only pictures). And it looks like questions are replied to weeks later (i.e., low traffic).

I have a pretty simple question about using a slide switch in online simulation and IDE. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Really the fact that it's an online simulation is irrelevant. The issue in question was with your code, and it would be the same on a real Arduino (lack of pullup / pulldown resistor on the input, or no INPUT_PULLUP set).

In this situation the question is not really about TinkerCAD - it's about your code or circuit.

However if there was something that worked on a real Arduino but not on TinkerCAD, you'd certainly be better asking about it at TinkerCAD.

Comment: Should I delete my answer? It's at -1 still.